# Regex to search multiple numbers - Numbers within number - Same pattern

Tags: java, regex, apex

I have used regex to find number from a given string.My code is working fine for the most of the scenario.

But, Here is an example where i am facing issue.

String : **EU/EEA6123645789133113** this is the string from where i want to find number.

Pattern :[6][0-9]{9}  - which means that number should start with 6 and the length of the character will be 10. https://regex101.com/

Output is : **6123645789** , which is correct.

But in the same string u can see there is another number which start with 6 and length is 10.

String : EU/EEA**6123645789**133113

String : EU/EEA6123**6457891331**13

I want to fetch both the numbers **6123645789** and **6457891331**.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Comment: See [`(?=(6[0-9]{9}))`](https://regex101.com/r/VkF9sL/1), grab `matcher.group(1)` while iterating through matches.

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply !@WiktorStribiżew